# Calculated Column Field Date

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-view, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I need to calculate date based on other column
I'm using `=Date(Year([endDate]),1,1)` in a calculated field which needs to return data as DateTime, but it is giving me error:

> The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.

After that I tried to modify the view to take only the year from today date as a string like: `Trim(Text(Year([Today])))` and it is accepting the formula, but no results in the view.

Any suggestions what can be causing the problem? I prefer to make it work like in the 1-st option which I described, but if it is doable in the 2nd, it is also acceptable.

Comment: Which Language are you using on SharePoint Server? I have had a problem with the ',' in previous project. In some language packs the delimiter seems to be a ';' (semicolon) instead of a comma. Maybe it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a calculated column as a date you need to use your formula in below format:

```
=DATE(YEAR,MONTH,DAY)
```

Using the formula as you have added in question, I am able to create a calculated field which will be in date format. see below:

[image]

**Note**:

1. I have return this field as **Date and Time** (highlighted in above image).
2. Sometimes **comma(,) does not work** in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language on your site). So **in that case use semicolon(;)** instead of comma(,).

**Reference**: [Date and time formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)#date-and-time-formulas).

Comment: You were right. Maybe because of the regional settings, I should separate parametes by ';'. Thanks u a lot, u saved my day

Comment: Welcome. Glad it worked for you. Keep using this platform to ask any queries/questions.

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my end and the column works just as Ganesh showed. Also i tried with semicolon which pops with syntax error. Besides the possible language reason, try with a new column or new list to see if the issue remains.